# find phrase in list and get index

Tags: python, list

I have tried researching this but can't find anything like what I am looking for.

I am trying to find a specific phrase in a list. Here is a test list:

```
data = {"text":["Map:","Internet",
"Subscriptions","","Map:",
"Adult","Literacy","and",
"Numeracy","|","8"]}
```

I want to get the index position of the first word in a phrase I am looking for like: `Map: Adult Literacy and Numeracy`. The answer for this would be `4` since the first word of the phrase is `Map:`. However, there are 2 `Maps:` in the list and I only need to find the one that is apart of the whole phrase `Map: Adult Literacy and Numeracy`.

Here is what I tried:

```
teststring = "Map: Adult Literacy and Numeracy"
teststring_split = teststring.split(" ")

data = {"text":["Map:","Internet",
"Subscriptions","","Map:",
"Adult","Literacy","and",
"Numeracy","|","8"]}

if teststring in " ".join(data["text"]):
    idx = data["text"].index(teststring.split(' ')[0])
    print(idx)
```

However it comes out it with `0` which makes sense because I am not sure how to get the specific `Maps:` that is apart of the phrase.

**EDIT** I am close because of @Alexander 's answer. I would have accepted his answer as correct but his answer only checks the first two index values in the phrase's split string. I would need to check the value as the list and phrases are dynamic and some phrases are very similar in wording.

Here is the code I have so far now:

```
for i in range(len(data['text'])):
    if data['text'][i] == teststring_split[0]:
        for m in range(len(teststring_split)):
            if data['text'][i + m] == teststring_split[m]:
                print(teststring_split[m])
```

This will output:

```
Map:
Map:
Adult
Literacy
and
Numeracy
```

So I can get a confirmation on the phrase as it prints out but I am not sure how to get the index of 4 after confirming the last word `Numeracy`

Comment: get the index of the second word as well ... and find the first index that is one less ... if you still have more than 1 option go on to the 3rd word and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension will work.  Just iterate through the data searching for values where the index == `Map:` and the following index is the second term of the teststring.

```
teststring = "Map: Adult Literacy and Numeracy"
teststring_split = teststring.split(" ")

data = {"text":["Map:","Internet",
"Subscriptions","","Map:",
"Adult","Literacy","and",
"Numeracy","|","8"]}

idxs = [i for i in range(len(data['text']))
        if data['text'][i] == teststring_split[0]
        and data['text'][i:i+len(teststring_split)] == teststring_split]
print(idxs)
```

Output:

```
[4]
```

Comment: This works for this scenario but in a dynamic sense, how would you be able to do this if you didn't know how many phrase words are simalar? I just made up the words but what if it was something like `Map: Adult and literacy` vs `Map: Adult and not literacy`? That would mean `0-2` in both indexes are similar. Is there a dynamic way to read/check out the whole list in an if statement? I can use it for now but I have some stuff where alot of words are the same till the very end. lol

Comment: I am very close because of your code. I updated my question to show my last attempts. You can see I am close but can't figure out how to get the index dynamically without checking only two index values.

Comment: @PythonKiddieScripterX  there you go now it tests the whole string

Comment: Hahaha its funny. I came up with an answer that is similar and I was able to post it but I saw you answer. I will give you the credit but I will make an answer for my version as well. 
`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start by, instead of converting `teststring` to a list, user `"".join(data)` to make `data` one string. This makes it much easier to scan through.

Then, use regular expressions to search for your phrase:

```
import re

teststring = "Map: Adult Literacy and Numeracy"
data = {"text":["Map:","Internet",
"Subscriptions","","Map:",
"Adult","Literacy","and",
"Numeracy","|","8"]}

data = "".join(data)
match = re.search(teststring, data)
print(match)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an answer at the same time @alexander fixed his answer. His is better as its less code but here is the version I came up with before I saw his answer:

```
for i in range(len(data['text'])):
    if data['text'][i] == teststring_split[0]:
        testindexchecker = 0
        for m in range(len(teststring_split)):
            if data['text'][i + m] == teststring_split[m]:
                print(teststring_split[m])
                testindexchecker = testindexchecker+1
            if testindexchecker == len(teststring_split):
                idxs = i
                print(i)
```